# Pin Name in Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

Recently I came across Parse's local datastore and found it very apt for my iOS application. However, I didn't fully understand the purpose of `[PFObject pinWithName:]` method. My initial understanding was, the name acts a namespace. So objects added to a pin with a name as pinOne, will not be fetched by a PFQuery for pin with name as pinTwo. But that wasn't the case when I implemented.

So what is the purpose of pinWithName and what feature does it provide?